# Hibernate generating strange tables names by join

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to delete some data on my webapp, I have a table named **post_it** and another table named **check_list**. the problem is, hibernate is generating a query combining the two names like, them only have a ManyToOne relationship:

```
    Hibernate: 
        delete 
        from
            post_it_check_list 
        where
            (
                post_it_id
            ) in (
                select
                    id 
                from
                    post_it 
                where
                    id=?
            )
```

Then it throws an SQLException...  `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'pinleaf.post_it_check_list' doesn't exist`.

I'm using Spring-Data JPA, so my query is:

```
 @Query(value = "delete from PostIt as p where p.id=:postItId")
```

These are the mapped entities involved:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "check_list")
public class CheckList extends BaseEntity {

    private PostIt postIt;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_it", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
    public PostIt getPostIt() {
        return postIt;
    }

    public void setPostIt(PostIt postIt) {
        this.postIt = postIt;
    }
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post_it")
public class PostIt extends BaseEntity {

    private String title;

    private String content;

    private Timestamp createdAt;

    private Timestamp dueDate;

    private Integer urgency;

    private boolean archived;

    private Board board;

    private Collection<CheckList> checkLists;

    private Collection<Tag> tags;

    @Column(name = "title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }


    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Column(name = "content")
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    public Timestamp getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Timestamp createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = now(createdAt);
    }

    private Timestamp now(Timestamp incommingTimestamp) {
        return incommingTimestamp == null ? Timestamp.valueOf(java.time.LocalDateTime.now()) : incommingTimestamp;
    }

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    @Column(name = "due_date")
    public Timestamp getDueDate() {
        return dueDate;
    }

    public void setDueDate(Timestamp dueDate) {
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "urgency")
    public Integer getUrgency() {
        return urgency;
    }

    public void setUrgency(Integer urgency) {
        this.urgency = urgency;
    }

    @Column(name = "archived")
    public boolean isArchived() {
        return archived;
    }

    public void setArchived(boolean archived) {
        this.archived = archived;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "board", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    public Board getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public void setBoard(Board board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    public Collection<CheckList> getCheckLists() {
        return checkLists;
    }

    public void setCheckLists(Collection<CheckList> checkLists) {
        this.checkLists = checkLists;
    }

    @ManyToMany
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @JoinTable(name = "post_it_tags",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_it", nullable = true),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag", nullable = true))
    public Collection<Tag> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(Collection<Tag> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different unidirectional associations between your two entities. One is a ManyToOne from CheckList to PostIt:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
@JoinColumn(name = "post_it", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
public PostIt getPostIt() {
    return postIt;
}
```

and the second one is a OneToMany from PostIt to CheckList, which has nothing to do with the first one:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
public Collection<CheckList> getCheckLists() {
    return checkLists;
}
```

Since you didn't specify how this unidirectional OneToMany is mapped, Hibernate assumes the default, which is to use a join table between the two tables.

If your intention is to have a single, bidirectional association, then the second one must be marked as the inverse of the first one using the `mappedBy` attribute:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "postIt", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
public Collection<CheckList> getCheckLists() {
    return checkLists;
}
```

Note that you're making your life difficult by using this delete query. You could simply use

```
em.remove(em.getReference(PostIt.class, id));
```